# Accordion Menu is closing after click on link?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an Accordion Menu using Bootstrap. I found a solution [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) and it works very well, however, when I clicks on link of options menu in the last panel it is closing and I don't know how could I fix this trouble, it needs to mantain the second menu opened and then close the first. I think it is happen because the page is reloading. So, how could I fix this ?

**Accordion**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading bg-red" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Pesquisas
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div><!--/title-->
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">                    
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("viewAnaliseAdmin", "Pesquisa")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Recebidas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("viewPesquisaEmAnaliseAdmin", "Pesquisa")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Análise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("viewPesquisaAprovadaAdmin", "Pesquisa")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Aprovadas</a></li>                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/panel 1-->

    <div class="panel panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading bg-red" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Configurações
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div><!--/title-->
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Estado")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Estados</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Condado")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Condados</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("viewAllAdmin","Usuario")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> Usuários</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/panel 2-->


</div><!--/panel group-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. I did a fix to help me to control the accordions and it works well.

I did

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading bg-red" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" id="collapseOnee" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Pesquisas
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div><!--/title-->
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">                    
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("viewAnaliseAdmin", "Pesquisa")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Recebidas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("viewPesquisaEmAnaliseAdmin", "Pesquisa")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Análise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("viewPesquisaAprovadaAdmin", "Pesquisa")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Aprovadas</a></li>                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/panel 1-->

    <div class="panel panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading bg-red" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Configurações
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div><!--/title-->
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Estado")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Estados</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Condado")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Condados</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("viewAllAdmin","Usuario")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> Usuários</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/panel 2-->


</div><!--/panel group-->
```

**JQuery Fix**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem');
    if (collapseItem === '') {
        var collapseItem = $('#collapseOnee').attr('aria-controls');
        localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', collapseItem);
        collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem');
    }
    $(collapseItem).collapse('show')
});


$('.collapsed').on('click', function () {
    var collapseItem = '#' + $(this).attr('aria-controls'); 
    localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', collapseItem);    
});
```